# How to get around error running snap app because it can't access $HOME/.inputrc

Tags: snap

I understand why the error is happening. I understand snap is strict about this. However, I would expect there would be some way to manually tell snap that it's ok to access a particular file, or add a file to it's environment, or something like that to get around the error.

I'm working with the spark-client snap app. It's been working fine. I just added a .inputrc file to my home dir, and now it fails because inside spark-client.spark-shell, it being a REPL, there is code that sees the file, but can't read it. I notice that when running `snap run --shell spark-client.spark-shell`, the snap app can see all the files, but it can't read them (`cat .inputrc` -> permission denied). Is there some how I can get around this? Something like:

1. Give it access? `snap connect {something with :personal-files}`: can't because only the snap author can add plugs/slots?
2. Copy the file into the snap app? Can't because `/snap/spark-client/current` is a mounted, read-only file system.

I saw someone suggest running the command directly and not as a snap command. That would be ok with me. I found the command `/snap/spark-client/current/opt/spark/bin/spark-shell` but apparently something runs around it first because there are env vars it's expecting that aren't set, so I can't just run it directly. Is there a straightforward way to figure out exactly what is run as a snap app so I can run that not within snap?

Comment: You should be able to add files to `~/snap` and subsidiary directories.

Comment: I see that directory and am able to write to it. But doing so doesn't resolve the error. I tried putting it in ~/snap/spark-client/current/ and ~/snap/spark-client/current/home/jshellman/, but it did not resolve the error I'm seeing. It's looking for an absolute path `/home/jshellman/.inputrc`.